# Size of Chrome notifications

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am building an extension which give user notifications using the createHTMLNotification call, but I am having some trouble figuring out the relevant size restrictions to avoid getting ugly black horizontal and vertical scrollbars (On Ubuntu 12.04 Linux at least).

Does anybody have any pointers to documentation giving some hints about what maximum sizes I should be aiming for, hopefully cross-platform?

Comment: These days on OS X you're bound to the size of a "notification" popup which is basically one long title line on top and one long "body" line. FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experiments on my own laptop running Chrome on Linux Version 21.0.1145.0 dev give me a maximum size of 284 by 144 pixels before scrollbars appear. I have no idea whether this is system specific or not, but assuming Chrome supports native notifications for at least some platforms that have them, I guess putting too much effort into pixel perfect notifications may not guarantee nice results.

As for making sure the scrollbars do not appear inside the notification, there is another small challenge as well (which maybe is not be related to the notification API at all); setting the `height` and `max-height` (and similarily for the width) does not cut it on it's own.

In my case I needed to style a list of items in a notification, and what I ended up doing was using the following html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: .73em;
      }
      div#note {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 144px;
        max-height: 144px;
        width: 284px;
      }
      div.noteline {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        line-height: 1.2em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=\"note\">#{params.html}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My template references (`#{params.html}`) is basically populated with rows containing :

```
<div class="noteline">Some possibly large line that would overflow item 123</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

maximum size on Windows Version 20.0.1132.47 (stable 144678) is 300 by 160 pixels.