# Change size of google chrome desktop notification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

Is any method to change size of notification window? I mean [these notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did not find it documented, but based on trial and error it seems it is fixed size horisontally (284px), and flexible vertically (up to 144px). Anything larger and you get (really ugly) scrollbars.

You may also want to check out:

[Size of Chrome notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761641/size-of-chrome-notifications/10761802#10761802)

I've also noticed the "Twitter Notifier" extension having the same issues (and scrollbars when tweets sometimes overflow).